# how to update all snap packages

Tags: apt, snap

I saw this:

> 44 packages can be update

so I did this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

that didn't work. how to update the packages it's talking about?

Comment: The packages it's talking about are not snap packages, ie. a `sudo apt full-upgrade` will upgrade your deb packages that can be updated.   *Please don't use pictures of text, but copy/paste the text into your question*

Answer (score 3):

The packages it's talking about are not snap packages, ie. a `sudo apt full-upgrade` will upgrade your deb packages that can be updated.

Normally I'd use a `sudo apt update` to update the software lists so it finds all packages that can be updated, but your system has already detected 44 packages that can be upgraded.  It may be worthwhile doing `sudo apt update` to ensure it's not going to find some more when very soon, but it's optional.

A `sudo apt upgrade` will upgrade most (if not all) packages, but `sudo apt full-upgrade` upgrades all [deb] packages on your system from your software lists.  Snap & other types of packages use different tools; these commands work on core deb packages.

From `man apt`

> ```
>    upgrade (apt-get(8))
>        upgrade is used to install available upgrades of all packages currently installed on the system from the
>        sources configured via sources.list(5). New packages will be installed if required to satisfy dependencies,
>        but existing packages will never be removed. If an upgrade for a package requires the removal of an installed
>        package the upgrade for this package isn't performed.
>
>    full-upgrade (apt-get(8))
>        full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed
>        to upgrade the system as a whole.
> ```